# how to control the space between two sections in bootstrap on small screens

Tags: html, css

while I am making a responsive site with bootstrap, I give min-height 100vh for both the home and about section. it looks nice for the large screen, but for the small screen, there is more space between the home section and the about section. how can I control that space for the small screen? I tried media queries to control the space between the home and about section for the small screen. I can't fix this. so tell me how to control that.

```css
.row {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: flex-end !important;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.first__para {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.landing__btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0275d8;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.landing__btn::after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 0px;
  opacity: ;
  background: #0275d8;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .3s;
}

.landing__btn:hover::after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 105px;
  background: #0275d8;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .3s;
  transform-origin: 0%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.about__head {
  color: #0275d8
}

.about__para {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.about__btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0275d8;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.about__btn::after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 0px;
  opacity: ;
  background: #0275d8;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .3s;
}

.about__btn:hover::after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 130px;
  background: #0275d8;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .3s;
  transform-origin: 0%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<!--landing page-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <h1 class="text-primary">the vollmonds</h1>
      <p class="first__para">Businesses get blinded by the allure of a large subscription list, <br>but unengaged subscribers aren't just not interested in what you're sending, they're actually harming your deliverability</p>
      <a href="#" class="landing__btn">for more<span></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--landing-page-->

<!--about-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
      <img src="https://cdni.iconscout.com/illustration/premium/thumb/startup-business-1460503-1234533.png" alt="marketting">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
      <h1 class="about__head">about</h1>
      <p class="about__para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, nisi dicta voluptatem cumque eius, <br>facere veritatis beatae rerum maxime ea accusamus, cum dolore ipsam quasi fugiat sit ullam error quas!</p>
      <p class="about__para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, nisi dicta voluptatem cumque eius, <br>facere veritatis beatae rerum maxime ea accusamus, cum dolore ipsam quasi fugiat sit ullam error quas!</p>
      <a href="#" class="about__btn">learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--about-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding some CSS that will increase margin on top of additional `.container` elements (or any class you name them), and then a media query to remove the margin if you desire. Code below for reference

```css
.row {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: flex-end !important;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.first__para {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.landing__btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0275d8;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.landing__btn::after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 0px;
  opacity: ;
  background: #0275d8;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .3s;
}

.landing__btn:hover::after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 105px;
  background: #0275d8;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .3s;
  transform-origin: 0%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.about__head {
  color: #0275d8
}

.about__para {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.about__btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0275d8;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.about__btn::after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 0px;
  opacity: ;
  background: #0275d8;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .3s;
}

.about__btn:hover::after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  width: 130px;
  background: #0275d8;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .3s;
  transform-origin: 0%;
  z-index: 10;
}


/* New CSS */
.container + .container {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .container + .container {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--landing page-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <h1 class="text-primary">the vollmonds</h1>
      <p class="first__para">Businesses get blinded by the allure of a large subscription list, <br>but unengaged subscribers aren't just not interested in what you're sending, they're actually harming your deliverability</p>
      <a href="#" class="landing__btn">for more<span></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--landing-page-->

<!--about-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
      <img src="https://cdni.iconscout.com/illustration/premium/thumb/startup-business-1460503-1234533.png" alt="marketting">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
      <h1 class="about__head">about</h1>
      <p class="about__para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, nisi dicta voluptatem cumque eius, <br>facere veritatis beatae rerum maxime ea accusamus, cum dolore ipsam quasi fugiat sit ullam error quas!</p>
      <p class="about__para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, nisi dicta voluptatem cumque eius, <br>facere veritatis beatae rerum maxime ea accusamus, cum dolore ipsam quasi fugiat sit ullam error quas!</p>
      <a href="#" class="about__btn">learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--about-->
```